# How to import CSV file with white-space in header with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.Text library for reading from CSV files in C#.

I would like to know how to deserialize CSV to objects where CSV contains white space separated header ?

I am using this code to deserialize CSV to **empClass** object:

```
  List<empClass> objList = File.ReadAllText(filePath).FromCsv<List<empClass>>();
```

If I have a csv file like this

```
EmpId,Employee Name,Employee Address 
12,JohnSmith,123 ABC Street
```

and my class is like

```
public class empClass{
public string EmpId;
public string Employee_Name;
public string Employee_Address;
}
```

It populates **EmpId** but it doesn't populate **Employee Name** and **Employee Address** as it contains the white-space in the header.

Will be grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The POCO class needs to match the property names of the CSV which has spaces in it, replacing it with an underscore doesn't make it match, you should also use public properties when using ServiceStack's serializers.

Since properties can't have spaces you can try using an alias, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmpClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="Employee Name")]
    public string EmployeeName  { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="Employee Address")]
    public string EmployeeAddress  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I was using public properties but forgot to write it here.